# Android service, compare hour

Tags: android, android-service

my problem is that I want to run a service that compares the current time of the device. And a "x" hour make some things.
But I don't have idea how can I make that.
Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

Schedule a repeating alarm using AlarmManager (see this [training lesson](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)).

Then in the [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), compare the current time with the list of times when you want to do some things if matches do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a thread in your service which checks the time at particular intevrvals. These intervals can be defined by you by putting this statement:
Thread.sleep(time_in_milliseconds);
in your Thread's "run" method. 
You can then use the SimpleDateFormat class to get the current time and compare hours with desired value. Once it is equal to the desired value, you can perform whatever task you wanted to do. Consider going through the SimpleDateFormat oracle docs for more detail and learning about Threads in case you don't know anything about them.